# Flutter Text shows question marks for characters ąčęėįšųūž

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

I have a simple text made like this:

```
var buttonTextStyle = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white);
Text("Žemėlapis", style: buttonTextStyle)
```

But letters ąčęėįšųūž are shown as question marks instead. When coding for Android or iOS, default font usually would support them just fine. What should I do?

Comment: are you using MaterialApp/Material?  That's should be using default font for your app. If you see that is not working, you can always use a custom font that has "ąčęėįšųūž".

Comment: Use a custom font and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried those characters on my Flutter example and are able to show it correctly. Did you tried on a real device? Did you tried with more languages available on your device?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I'm trying on an iOS simulator. It should be a default font.